# Primes in intervals of special form

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p_n$ be $n$-th prime number. Now define the sequence of intervals in this way $i(n)=[p_n \cdot p_{n+1}, p_n \cdot p_{n+2}$]. For example the first interval would be $[6,10]$, the second would be $[15,21]$, the third would be $[35,55]$ and so on...

> Is it true that there is at least one prime in every $i(n)$?